# Unity Perforce Mapping Failure

Tags: unity-game-engine, perforce, perforce-client-spec

So after using unity's asset server for quite a while I decided I would try Perforce as it seemed like a good alternative and a viable way to work with people without the pro license. I am using Windows version of Unity 5 and a Linux install of P4V.

The problem I am getting is this error

```
The Client path
       //ProjectName
maps to this folder 
       ~\Perforce\ProjectName
which is not a parent directory of the projects root:
       C:\Users\...\ProjectName`
```

After searching the internet I found nothing as to what exactly this means so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 0):

Two pieces of configuration data aren't matching up:

1. The client workspace root, which in your case appears to be set to "~\Perforce\ProjectName", and
2. The project root, which in your case appears to be set to "C:\Users...\ProjectName"

P4Connect is expecting the "project root" (C:\Users...) to be "under" the "workspace root" (~\Perforce...)

I suspect the problem is in the use of the Unix-y tilde (~) character to mean your home directory. In general, Windows software doesn't expand the tilde character automatically; that is a Unix-y behavior.

Try replacing the ~ with the full path to your project root.

And make sure that your project root is located inside of your workspace root.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have been more specific. The ~ is to shorten the path in example. the "maps to this folder" is actually like:

\home\username\Perforce\ProjectName

Comment: \home\username\Perforce\ProjectName -- is that under C:\Users\...\ProjectName? It doesn't sound like it, as \home and \Users are two different root directories.

Comment: right, but they should be different root directories as one is on Linux (perforce file location) and windows (unity file location). I might be misunderstanding, but it seems like you are saying that the server files and the client files need to be in the same path on both machines which doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: None of these configuration settings are for configuring server files, assuming by 'server' you mean the Perforce server. You need to have a client workspace on the same machine where you are running Unity. You can have multiple Perforce workspaces. The P4Connect software will take your Unity objects and check them in to the Perforce server, which is presumably running on a server in your machine room.

Comment: It strikes me that I may not have have set the server up correctly then so excuse me for this slightly off topic diversion. I had installed P4 and P4D on my Linux server, set the P4D server root to a folder and left the port alone to stay 1666 and ran P4. I then installed P4V on the linux machine to make sure that the installation was successful, of which i am no longer sure. I had assumed that p4connect was all unity needed since the documentation i had read in regards to it had made no reference to needing anything else. I guess the question is how do i confirm its installed correctly?

Comment: That's fine, and makes sense. Perforce is a client-server system so indeed the server on Linux can be accessed from P4Connect on your workstation running Unity. But you will probably find it convenient to install P4V on your Windows workstation as well, so that you can directly access Perforce from P4V on your workstation. Your other developers might only need Unity+P4Connect, but having P4V present as well lets you access all of the Perforce features from your PC.

Comment: Yeah, having it for my computer with unity makes sense so I will install it. How do I confirm that my perforce service was installed correctly though?

Comment: By "Perforce service", you mean the p4d server on your Linux machine? You could work through some of the Perforce tutorial materials, using the P4V that you install on your PC, talking to the p4d on your Linux server. That would give you confidence in your setup, I think. There are a lot of docs on the Perforce website to help you.